# Email notification when user/respondent edits their Google form response NOT when the spreadsheet is edited

Tags: triggers, notifications

We use a google form to collect information from our volunteers. The admin works in the linked google spreadsheet. If volunteers have to update their details, they are asked to do so via the "Edit Response" link that we send to them after submiting the form initially (executed by a trigger in App Script).

I need to be notified when the USER edits their response through the "Edit Response" link. I am NOT looking to be notified when the spreadsheet has been edited. Any chance this can be done? I know the Sheet will palce a flag on the cell and note "Responder updated this value."

I am not a programmer! Ive just started tinkering with App Script to automate some processes.

Any help would be appreciated.

I searched online for help!